# Do not save workbench state in a eclipse RCP app

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am devoloping an application with eclipse RCP. This application should alwaysshow a certain perspective when started. But the application saves it workbench state and when restarted it shows the same perspective it had when it was closed. I tried to add

```
public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer){
    configurer.setSaveAndRestore(false);
}
```

to my `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` class, but it did'nt work. I also thought of selection the right perspective, but I don't know where to add such a piece of code.

How can my application always show the same perspective on startup?

Comment: You might have to delete the saved workbench state file manually once to clear up the old saved state.

Comment: I tried, but it had no effect: I started with the "clear workspace" option and saw how the "workbench.xmi"-file got deleted, but it appeared immediately after closing the application, even though setAndRestore was set to false.

Comment: The xmi file will be created but the 3.x state stored as part of the file should not be included. You could try the `-clearPersistedState` flag to ignore the xmi file altogether (not sure if this works for 3.x apps).

Comment: If you mean adding `-clearPersistedState` to the program arguments then that does not work with 3.x apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if you always want the same start perspective, you can set the default perspective during startup.

```
public class Application implements IApplication {
    public Object start(IApplicationContext content){
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry().setDefaultPerspective("youperspective here");

        //other code...
    }

    //other code...
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This only works if you enable "Clear workspace" in your run configurations. My current solution is to delete the workbench file during program startup.

Answer (score 2):

Too late for you but maybe usefull for other people.

As @Aiden says, we add `-clearPersistedState` to the program arguments in run configurations.

It worked for us in e4 with Eclipse Neon 4.6.